# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, dictionary

Im getting this error when trying to get a value from a dictionary.
here is my code!

```
test = {
    "Key1", "Value1",
    "Key2", "Value2",
}

index = input("Enter a key: ")
print("Here is your desired value: ", test.get(index))
```

Comment: That is a set, not a dictionary. Use `:` between each key and its value to get a dictionary.

Comment: you can try `test[index]`

Answer (score 1):

below code makes test a dictionary, see the `:` between key and value

```
test = {
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": "Value2",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `:` between key and value. [Python Dictionary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/)

```
test = {
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": "Value2",
}

index = input("Enter a key: ")
print("Here is your desired value: ", test.get(index)) # or test[index]
```

This should work.

Comment: `.get` is always safer than `[ ]`. Unless you need a `KeyError`, it's safer to use `.get.`

Answer (score 0):

You are defining dictionary in wrong way, try this:

```
test = {
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": "Value2",
}

index = input("Enter a key: ")
print("Here is your desired value: ", test.get(index))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Jan  1 15:20:27 2021

@author: Pietro
"""

test = {
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": "Value2",
}

index = input("Enter a key: ")
print("Here is your desired value: ", test.get(index))
```

Here info about : [Python Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)